# How to fixed keylistener on JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, barcode, keylistener

I have a Java swing application, so I have a simple Text box with KeyListener and I have a barcode reader (USB), when the barcode reader write the number on this textbox, I chek the code and I process it. But I have the problem the code can have from 4 to 13 digits. So I have this code

```
public class KeyListenerCodice implements KeyListener{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent click) {

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        printIt("Released", keyEvent);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        printIt("Typed", keyEvent);
    }

    private void printIt(String title, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if(textCodice.getText().length()>=4 && textCodice.getText().length()<=13)
        {
            if(mappaArticoliScontrini.get(textCodice.getText().toUpperCase())!=null){
                inserisciProdotto();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But sometimes the code have 13 digits but if the barcode reader is not very fast, the keylistener process only 4 or 5 or 6 digits and this is a problem.

How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is don't.  Use a `DocumentFilter` to change what gets entered into a `JTextComponent` or a `DocumentListener` if you want to know when the content of the field changes.

`KeyListener` will not take into account what happens if the user pastes text into the field or if the field is modified programmatically

See [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details

If your bar code scanner is injecting key events into the event queue, you may wish to inject an artificial delay into the `DocumentFilter`, as you won't want to process the field until AFTER all the key strokes are entered.

For example...

This basically uses a Swing `Timer` set to short delay (250 milliseconds in this case), each time the field is updated (and the `DocumentListener` is notified), it restarts the `Timer`.  This means there must be delay of at least 250 milliseconds from the last update before the `Timer` can trigger the registered `ActionListener` and update the label.

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Timer updateTimer;
    private JTextField field;
    private JLabel label;

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        updateTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(field.getText());
            }
        });
        updateTimer.setRepeats(false);

        label = new JLabel("...");
        field = new JTextField(14);
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                processUpdate();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                processUpdate();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                processUpdate();
            }

        });

        add(field, gbc);
        add(label, gbc);
    }

    protected void processUpdate() {
        updateTimer.restart();
    }

}
```

You might like to play around with the delay a little.

The bar code scanner may also be inserting a <kbd>Enter</kbd> key into the event queue, so it might be worth testing the field by registering an `ActionListener` against it

Comment: I don't understand what is the different between KeyListener and DocumentListener

Comment: @bircastri A `DocumentListener` will notify you when ever the contents of the `Document` changes, where as the `KeyListener` will only notify you key events.  Try adding a `KeyListener` to a `JTextField` and call `setText` or paste text into the field, the `KeyListener` will no be notified.  As general rule of thumb, don't use `KeyListener` on text components

Comment: But when the barcode write on a JTextField, I don't call setText, the barcode reader is like a keyboard and you can write

Comment: The `DocumentListener` is the preferred means by which you monitor changes to the a text component...